# Unit vector on nested vector

Tags: vectors

I got a vector of form $Z=\{\{x_1,y_1\},\{x_2,y_2\},...,\{x_n,y_n\}\}$ and I need to find its unit vector in a way that $||Z||=1$. How I would be able to do that?

I already tried several way and none of them gave me a satisfying result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try dividing the vector by its length?

Comment: how is the norm defined?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: It is okay guys, I just found what the author meant and I was doing it correctly, my mistake is coming from somewhere else